# Visual Studio Code disappears in Tabular model when there is a syntax error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tabular, dax

When building Tabular model using MS Visual Studio and writing some metric (DAX), the whole written code will disappear when I write it with any mistake generating syntax error. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? That there would be option to only get error message there is an syntax error, but not remove the code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently no option to prevent losing the code. For this reason I used to take the (very unwieldy) workaround of copying my new measure's formula before committing it to the model. (I even did this when modifying existing measures!)

I have since moved onto using [DAX Studio](http://daxstudio.codeplex.com/) to build up more complicated measures, and I recommend it to everyone writing DAX, as it avoids the syntax error and acts more like a traditional IDE - and it's 100% free and open source. [Here's a nice tutorial on building DAX measures using DAX Studio.](https://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/using-dax-studio-to-create-powerpivot-measures/)